# Omitting exogenous variables from first stage regression 2SLS - fixed effects, lagged Y variables

Tags: fixed-effects-model, instrumental-variables, lags

I have a problem which, in its general form, has been addressed on this forum: can you omit exogenous variables from the first stage regression in a 2SLS estimation? (see: [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/283860/including-not-all-exogenous-variables-in-the-first-stage-iv-regression) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/177747/why-do-you-put-all-the-exogenous-variables-into-the-first-and-second-stage-of-2s)). The answer in both cases seems to be a clear "no", with the respondents suggesting that doing so will lead to an inconsistent estimator. I am not sure, however, how to apply this logic to two subsets of exogenous second stage variables: fixed effects, and lagged Y.

First: **fixed effects (FEs)**. Since my data is in panel format, allowing me to observe multiple individuals *i* over time *t*, in the second stage I use individual *i* / year *T* fixed effects (note: *t* captures days, so this strategy leaves plenty of variation in the variable of interest that also varies by *t*). However, my best candidate instrument *z* only varies across  *i* and years (*T*), but not within years. As a result, using *i* / *T* FEs in the first stage will suck out all the variation in *z*. However, if I only use *i* FEs, this will preserve variation in *z* that should allow me to instrument. **My question is**: just how bad would it be to use FEs that are less complicated in the first stage than in the second stage?

Second: **lagged choice variable**. There is good reason to believe there is inertia in the customer's decision when choosing the dependent variable *y_t*, and so I include a lagged variable *y_t-1* as an explanatory variable. **My question is**: should I also include *y_t-1* in the first stage, even though it makes no sense, intuitively, why *y_t-1* would impact my endogenous variable *w*?

Thank you in advance for any help on this matter,

~K

P.S. This is my first post on this forum, so I apologize if I failed to follow etiquette in any way

Comment: Welcome to stats.stackexchange.com.The question has been crafted  well.